# Connect AngularJS app to backend using credentials (Beginner/Intermediate)

Tags: angularjs, curl, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, basic-authentication

After quite an extensive research period , I have narrowed down my problem . I had a curl request

```
curl -X POST -vu sampleapp:samplekey http://sampleurl:8090/oauth/token -H "Accept: application/json" -d "password=pass&username=username&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write&client_secret=samplekey&client_id=sampleapp"
```

which was sending me a response like

```
    {     
"access_token":"blah", 
"token_type":"bearer", 
"refresh_token":"blah", 
"expires_in":43199,     
"scope":"read write"
}
```

I have a client app (AngularJS) which is trying to talk to a backend. It has all CORS headers and methods implemented on the server side.

I get the login info from the client and post it to the api to try and get an access token.

Now , when I'm writing (updated after 1st answer below by Issac) my login function below. I was told that I need 3 header values : **Authorization,Accept and Content-type**

```
var _login = function (loginData) {

var theauthdata = Base64.encode('sampleapp:samplekey');

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var headers2 = {
        'Accept' : 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic' + theauthdata,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    };



        // For JSON authorization 
        var data = {
            'grant_type': 'password',
            'scope' : 'read write',
            'username' : loginData.username,
            'password' : loginData.password,
            // withCredentials : true,
            'client_id' : 'sampleapp',
            'client_secret' : 'samplekey'
        }

         $http.post(serviceBase + 'token', data, { headers: headers2},{withCredentials:true})

        .success(function (response) 
        {

            localStorageService.set('authorizationData', { token: response.access_token, userName: loginData.userName });

            _authentication.isAuth = true;
            _authentication.userName = loginData.userName;

            deferred.resolve(response);

        }).error(function (err, status) {
            _logOut();
            deferred.reject(err);
        });

        return deferred.promise;

    };
```

Even after adding the required headers,I am getting a `401 error` from the api server in the process.

In the curl request -u part denotes the url uname/pwd and I want to make sure I'm writing the call in a correct way. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT/UPDATE :** As the first comment for the question goes , yes I'm supposed to send username/password combination of the URL and not the user data.

That's what the -u part of the curl request means I'm guessing.

I did some research after the first answer and apparently I'm trying [Basic HTTP authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) ? But I want to clarify that I'm still sending the clientUserData ( login info ) as a payload. Am I doing it correctly then ? I was under the impression that I was doing the [resource-owner-grant-credentials](http://ox.gluu.org/doku.php?id=oxauth:resourceownerpasswordcredentialsgrant) but this is basic http auth as I'm being told ? Obviously, I'm new to OAuth and  confused. Can someone please elaborate which method I'm implementing based on the curl call above ? Basically, I'm trying to mimic the curl call given above.

**UPDATE :** I've updated the login code. I have an factory setup to handle the functions and I built a Base64 factory as well to encode the data. I can't help but think I'm still doing something wrong or a making a call wrong ?

Comment: You mean there is a username / password to POST to the URL in addition to the username / password that is passed for logging in?

Comment: what do you mean by "username and password for the url"? Why you have 2 separate user credentails?

Comment: have you try http://sampleapp:samplekey@sampleurl:8090/oauth/token

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're asking about how to use Basic HTTP Authentication with $http service.  Here's how to do that.

```
var authdata = Base64.encode(username + ':' + password);
var headers2 = {
    'Accept' : 'application/json',
    'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + authdata;
}
```

You'll need to include a library to encode to Base64, like this one:

```
var keyStr = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=';
var Base64 = {
    encode: function (input) {
        var output = "";
        var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
        var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
        var i = 0;

        do {
            chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
            chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
            chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

            enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
            enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
            enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
            enc4 = chr3 & 63;

            if (isNaN(chr2)) {
                enc3 = enc4 = 64;
            } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
                enc4 = 64;
            }

            output = output +
                keyStr.charAt(enc1) +
                keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
                keyStr.charAt(enc3) +
                keyStr.charAt(enc4);
            chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
            enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";
        } while (i < input.length);

        return output;
    },

    decode: function (input) {
        var output = "";
        var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
        var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
        var i = 0;

        // remove all characters that are not A-Z, a-z, 0-9, +, /, or =
        var base64test = /[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g;
        if (base64test.exec(input)) {
            window.alert("There were invalid base64 characters in the input text.\n" +
                "Valid base64 characters are A-Z, a-z, 0-9, '+', '/',and '='\n" +
                "Expect errors in decoding.");
        }
        input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

        do {
            enc1 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc2 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc3 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc4 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

            chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
            chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
            chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

            output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);

            if (enc3 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
            }
            if (enc4 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
            }

            chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
            enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";

        } while (i < input.length);

        return output;
    }
};
```

The code is modified from [here](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/05/26/AngularJS-Basic-HTTP-Authentication-Example.aspx).

**UPDATE:**

Your curl request is authenticating itself in 2 different ways.

1. With Basic HTTP Authentication, here: `-vu sampleapp:samplekey`
2. With user login credentials, here: `-d "password=pass&username=username"`

Part 1 is taken care of by the header (i.e. `header2`).  Part 2 is taken care of by the username and password in the `data` variable.  It seems a bit like overkill to me, but there are some scenarios where having double authentication is required.

**UPDATE:**
You're missing a space after `Basic`, the line should read:

```
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + theauthdata,
```

Comment: @issac-mann can you please elaborate on my queries ? Thanks in advance :) !

Comment: @issac-mann Hey Issac I just updated the question. Please see if you can. Thanks a lot for all the help !